# why Design changes when website get hosted?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to add a data table in to my asp.net web application.While I was running the application from visual studio design look like this :

[image]

But when I opened the same solution as a website, design changes to:

[image: Table design after hosting]

Why this kind of error happens ? I checked  `<link href="css/style.datatables.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and `<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>` both file locations look ok ,And there are no repeated links .How can we test these type of errors before hosting (cz it looks fine when I was running from visual studio) ?

PLEASE help me to find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your container width make your outer container width 100% and see it will look like VS.

and regarding sort arrow you need to set no-repeat property for background image

for eg: .sort{ background:no-repeat url('sort.png')}